# values get undefined after then of promise nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm facing a problem with my code... I make a query to my DB to check if a mac address of a array of macs is on the DB. If I have any result I return the count of macs in my DB and if is > 0 then I don't add nothing cause the mac already is listed, but if my result.count = 0 then I will add a new record.

My new record just have the mac address. For this I'm trying:

```
var countRepetidos = 0
var countPromises = []

if (obj.data.list != {} && obj.data.list.length > 0) {
  var aux = obj.data["list"]
  countRepetidos = 0

  for (var i = 0; i < aux.length; i++) {
    countPromises.push(Database.Probing.getMacAdress(aux[i]).then(function(data) {
      console.log("probing countPromises aux[i] ", aux[i])

      if (data.count > 0) {
        countRepetidos += 1
      } else {
        Database.Probing.addMac(aux[i])
      }

      return Promise.resolve()
    }))
  }

  Promise.all(countPromises).then(() => {
    dataRepeated = [obj.data.stats.since, countRepetidos]
    listaRepeated.push(dataRepeated)

    console.log("probing listaRepeated --> ", listaRepeated)

    if (listaRepeated != [] && (listaRepeated[0][0] != undefined && listaRepeated[0][1] != undefined)) {
      Database.Probing.getLastTimestamp("probing_repeated", device.id).then(function(data) {
        var lastTimestamp = data.date_part

        console.log('probing lastTimestamp ', lastTimestamp * 1000)

        if (lastTimestamp != listaRepeated[0][0] / 1000) {
          Controllers.Agregate.agregateData("probing_repeated", 5 * 60, listaRepeated, dbHistConnectionString, device.id, device.network_id, device.organization_id, ["time", "clients"])
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

The problem is after the then of Database.Probing.getMacAddress my aux[i] gets undefined and I need this value to insert into my DB.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to preserve the value of `i`. You can do this way:

```
for (var i = 0; i < aux.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    countPromises.push(
      Database.Probing.getMacAdress(aux[i]).then(function(data) {
        console.log("probing countPromises aux[i] ", aux[i])
        if (data.count > 0) {
          countRepetidos += 1
        } else {
          Database.Probing.addMac(aux[i])
        }

        return Promise.resolve()
      }))
  })(i)
}
```

Edit 1: As suggested by @lain, use `let` over `var`

```
 for (let i = 0; i < aux.length; i++) {}
```

Comment: I did not get what you mean?

Comment: })(i); this... in each part of the code? before Promise.all ? sorry

Comment: A cleaner way of doing this would be using `let` over `var`. `let` sets the value of `i` for the scope of the loop, whereas `var` sets the value of `i` for the outer function scope.

Comment: @AndréBastos just use the way I have used. You don't need to use `i` in eachline

Comment: @lain Thanks for suggestion.